# How can I print the results of pubr::compare_means?

Tags: r, tidyverse, ggpubr

I would like to copy and paste the results of a compare_means function.

```
# A tibble: 36 x 10
   keyword syllable .y.      group1 group2         p  p.adj p.format p.signif method  
   <chr>   <fct>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
 1 nali    1        duration 0      1      0.0327    0.75   0.03268  *        Wilcoxon
 2 nali    2        duration 0      1      0.734     1      0.73389  ns       Wilcoxon
 3 nali    3        duration 0      1      0.979     1      0.97859  ns       Wilcoxon
 4 nali    4        duration 0      1      0.0215    0.54   0.02149  *        Wilcoxon
 5 nali    5        duration 0      1      0.147     1      0.14725  ns       Wilcoxon
 6 nali    6        duration 0      1      0.112     1      0.11219  ns       Wilcoxon
 7 shenme  1        duration 0      1      0.00130   0.04   0.00130  **       Wilcoxon
 8 shenme  2        duration 0      1      0.0000325 0.0011 3.2e-05  ****     Wilcoxon
 9 shenme  3        duration 0      1      0.0375    0.83   0.03753  *        Wilcoxon
10 shenme  4        duration 0      1      0.112     1      0.11230  ns       Wilcoxon
# ... with 26 more rows
```

The question is the output is shown in console and I can't see "26 more rows". Is there quick and easy way to export or print the results so I can put them into a word file?

Comment: You can write the data to your clipboard using `writeClipboard(df)`, or `write.table(df, file = "clipboard")`, where the latter will be optimal for copy-pasting into e.g. Excel or Word. Another option to simply view the data is using RStudio command `View(df)`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing .`writeClipboard()` TIL. Looks like that will work for MS Windows, not Unix systems like macOS

Comment: use `options(tibble.print_max = Inf)` to override the default print limit https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/formatting.html#package-options

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for sharing.